# Polynomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I got stuck with an exercise while preparing for my exam, and could use a hint or two to move on...

Let $f(X) = a_n X^n+a_{n-1} X^{n-1}+ \cdots +a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $a_0\neq 0$

Assuming that $X\in \langle f(X)\rangle$ then prove: $n \leq 1$ and either $\langle f(X)\rangle = \langle X\rangle$ or $f(X) = \mathbb{Z}[X]$

I have shown that if $5 \in \langle f(X)\rangle$ then $n = 0 $ and $a_0\mid 5$, and got to at point where I have:

$$X\in \langle f(X)\rangle \Rightarrow X = \lambda f(x), \quad \lambda \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$$

Which tells me that $\deg(f(x))$ is either one or zero.

If it is $0$ then $f(X)$ is a unit

If $\deg(f(X))$ is 1 then $f(X)$ is irreducible and $\langle f(X)\rangle$ is a maximal ideal

Comment: Something seems wrong: if $\,(f) = (x)\,$ then $\,x\mid f\,$ so $\,a_0 = f(0) = 0,\,$ contra hypothesis. Please double-check the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I=\langle f(X)\rangle$ is a principal ideal, which means that every element of $I$ is divisible by $f(X)$. The only divisors of $X$ are the units and associates of $X$ itself, so if $X\in \langle f(X)\rangle $ then $f(X)$ is a unit or $f(X)$ is an associate of $X$. In the first case $I=\mathbb{Z}[X]$ because there exists a $g$ such that $fg=1$, and since $I$ is an ideal this means that for any $h\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ we have $h\cdot 1=h\in I$. In the second case we have $I=\langle X\rangle$ since $I$ consists precisely of the multiples of $X$.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I get the first case(where $f(X)$ is a unit), can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Nohr Please see my edit.

Comment: @Nøhr No problem.

Answer (score 0):

$X=f(X)g(X) \Rightarrow deg f(X) + deg g(X)=1 \Rightarrow deg f(X)=0,1.$ If $deg f(X)=0,$ then $f(X)$ is a constant. Say $f(X)=\lambda \in \mathbb Z.$ In this case equating the coefficient of $X$ from both side we get that $\lambda$ is actually a unit. (This part you got right.) Now let $f(X)=aX+b, a \neq 0.$ Since $X \in \langle f(X) \rangle,$ we must have $a$ is a unit and $b=0.$ (Why?) Thus $\langle f(X) \rangle = \langle X \rangle.$

Comment: If deg $f =0$, then $f$ is a unit.  Why?  This is true in $\Bbb Q[x]$, but not $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: It would be constant, not unit. One needs some more argument to show that it will be a unit actually. This part was missing. Now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the argument you added is correct.  You say that $\lambda$ is a unit.  So what then is $\lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: $f(X)=\lambda$ and $g(X)$ is a degree one polynomial, say $g(X)=cX+d, c,d \in \mathbb Z$ and $f(X)g(X)=X.$ Now equating the coefficient of $X$ from both side we get $\lambda \cdot c=1.$

Comment: Suppose $\lambda=2$, then $c=1/2\notin\Bbb Z$.  I'm sorry but the only units of $\Bbb Z[X]$ are $1$ and $-1$.  The units of $\Bbb Q[X]$ are the non-zero constants.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: If $\lambda = 2,$ then the polynomial equation $f(X)g(X)=X$ won't be satisfied. That's the main point here. A priori we have no knowledge what $\lambda$ will be, except that it is a (non-zero) constant. But the above mentioned equation forces that $\lambda$ is a unit.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood your argument.